# How to control house climate system

Tags: raspberry-pi

In my house I have a climate system and I want to control the     modes using RPI. I'm not very strong in electronics so my question is - How can I connect RPI GPIO to this hardware X2 switch? [image]

Like you see there is simple hardware switch with 13.5V in OFF state and 5mA current in ON state. Since there is small voltage and current I think relay or triac is too "hard" solution and I tested with NPN transistor [image] .Also I would appreciate advice on electrical safety .

but I'm not sure if it good schematic and solution...

Comment: 13.5V ??? what do letters A and N signify?

Comment: is X2-2 connected to safety ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXKwoy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Opto-isolated RPi control. Pull GPIO "low" to activate. Figure 2. Same circuit with less load on GPIO pins. Pull GPIO "high" to activate.*

The circuit you have shown would probably work fine. Just pull each of the lines (0), (2) and (3) to ground with a transistor. The problem is that we don't know for sure whether the ground in the controller is at the same ground as your RPi. If it isn't then we could have smoke.

To solve this you can use opto-isolators.

- Figure 1 shows the simple version. R2, 4 and 6 limit the current to the opto-LED to about 5 mA so check the datasheet for your opto-isolators to confirm that this is high enough.
- Figure 2 does the same thing but with less loading on the GPIO pins.
- The opto isolators ensure complete electrical isolation between the RPi and the controller.

Comment: Yes I have tested with one NPN transistor and resistor and all is worked, but I understood that it's better to optoisolate RPI. Thanks